# Larger databases (10GB+) left in "restore pending" state when Stored Proc is called from Powershell script

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012

I have this powershell script that works great for database which are 5GB and smaller. However it has a problems when it tries to databases which are bigger. The problem is that when this script completes to run the larger databases are left in restore-pending mode.

The goal of this script is to copy the latest SQL BAK files from the previous night to a folder called test.  Once the SQL BAK files are there the script proceed to go to the next step to restore each SQL BAK file to the SQL instance.

When this script runs for the smaller database it completes with no errors. However for the big databases it also completes with no errors but the database are left in restore pending mode.

```
$bak_path = "\\nas2\sqlbackups"
$yesterday = (Get-Date -hour 13 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(-1)
get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "SERVERXYZ*.bak" -Exclude *master*.**,*model*.**,*msdb*.** -File -recurse |
where {$_.CreationTime -gt $yesterday} | copy-item -Destination I:\test


do {

      $bak_path = "I:\TEST"
      Get-ChildItem -path $bak_path | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*SERVERXYZ*"}          |  select -last 1 |
      rename-item -newname {"Database.bak"}
      $Input = Get-ChildItem -path $bak_path Database.bak


      $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
      $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=SQLENTBAK;Database=test;Integrated Security=True"
      $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
      $SqlCmd.CommandText = "dbo.restoredatabase"
      $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
      $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
      $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
      $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
      $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
      $SqlConnection.Close()
      $DataSet.Tables[0]

      $FileName = "I:\TEST\Database.bak"
      if (Test-Path $FileName) {
      Remove-Item $FileName}           

} while (Get-ChildItem I:\TEST\)
```

I would appreciative any insight to why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you would think so, however I am running Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (SQL Server 11.0.5058).  One more thing, I am able to restore databases 10GB and larger manually via SSMS.

Comment: OK, I did some more testing and this is what I found.  My stored procedure dbo.restoredatabase works just fine with large databases.

Comment: OK, I did some more testing and this is what I found.  My stored procedure dbo.restoredatabase works just fine with large databases. Somehow it appears to be related to the Poweshell ISE or something else. Any ideas, my strenght is in TSQL not Powershell so I would appreciative any help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide `dbo.restoredatabase` but I would expect that you are timing out when executing that stored procedure and not rolling back when your connection terminates, since the default timeout is 30 seconds.

You need to change the `$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout` to be more generous, for instance 300 for 5 minutes. The length that is sufficient is based on a lot of factors.

Comment: For reference, the [default value is 30 seconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: That worked, interesting I did not know I needed to set a timeout limit.